# if Statement - Multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am looking to use an if statement to check whether e.currentTarget.id doesn't equal "alert" OR "history" and this is not working. Is there another way to check two conditions for an either/or situation like this one?

```
  var buttons = elt.find(":submit,:button,.clickable");
  buttons.unbind("click");
  buttons.click(function (e) {
    put({ "tag": "click",  "id": e.currentTarget.id});
    if(e.currentTarget.id != "alert" || e.currentTarget.id != "history"){
        $(".hide_on_click").hide();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Try to change the `||` to `&&`.  Remember DeMorgan's laws: `!p && !q === !(p || q)` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement will always be true since the id cannot equal two different strings and thus one of them will always be true.

```
  var buttons = elt.find(":submit,:button,.clickable");
  buttons.unbind("click");
  buttons.click(function (e) {
    put({ "tag": "click",  "id": e.currentTarget.id});
    if(e.currentTarget.id != "alert" && e.currentTarget.id != "history"){
        $(".hide_on_click").hide();
    }
  });
```

I am not sure what it is you want to do; but if you want to hide something when the id is none of those values try the above code.